Error after upgrading a deprecated babel plugin
After upgrading from @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from to @babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from, I get the following error when running this command
jest --config e2e/jest.config.js --bail

through a detox test suite:

Export namespace should be first transformed by
*@babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from 1 | export * as ContactsEntities from '•/contacts';

Here is the babel.config.js:
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      {
        globals: ['__scanCodes'],
      },
    ],
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: ['.ios.js', '.android.js', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
        alias: {
          '@app': './src/app',
          '@processes': './src/processes',
          '@screens': './src/screens',
          '@widgets': './src/widgets',
          '@features': './src/features',
          '@entities': './src/entities',
          '@shared': './src/shared',
        },
      },
    ],
    '@babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from',
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel', '@babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from'],
    },
  },
};

